# How to find out what repo I installed a chart from?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I can list my installed charts like this:

```
❯ helm list -A
NAME            NAMESPACE       REVISION        UPDATED                                 STATUS          CHART                   APP VERSION
cert-manager    cert-manager    2               2020-07-05 18:38:44.8954751 -0700 PDT   deployed        cert-manager-v0.15.2    v0.15.2
```

But how do I find out where I installed `cert-manager` from?

I assume it was `https://charts.jetstack.io` but is there any history on that? Can I find what command I used?

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no way to obtain the repo or URL from which the chart was installed, as a Helm chart is not tied to any remote location.

The command `helm get all installation-name` will give all the info about an installed chart such as the manifest, the given values and the computed ones, but **NOT** the url or origin of the chart.

There are several open bugs / requests such as https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/4256

It would be interesting if the origin could be available as part of the manifest info or something like that, but I think the origin is stripped completely from the helm client, so there's no info on where was the chart located from in the first place, once we are at installation time.